How to make the border of note dashed in PlantUML
I am using skinparam to change the default look of the note in PlantUML, everything seems to work except for the BorderStyle property. I want to make the border of the note dashed but it stays the same.
skinparam note {
    BorderStyle Dashed
    FontSize 10
    FontColor #00000090
    BackgroundColor LightBlue
}

Same skinparam works on rectangle without any issues.

It works with CSS styles:
https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuR8fBgdCIRNZyiilILMevbBmoSnB3GO9AHXnrNBPw2DB9nOhv74vvIHcSBdcfIZa0OMu75BpKe360000
@startuml
<style>
Note {
 LineStyle 2
}
</style>
Note as n
Blah
End note
@enduml

